# Can I run my selenium code so that it doesn't trigger cloudflare?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cloudflare

I'm writing a code that can help my dad get tee times for his golf course. At the moment, it scans through a series of n number of tabs for a button to book the tee time, but if it can't find one, it refreshes the page. The problem comes when it refreshes, as the page is protected by cloudflare, and thus my code gets blocked ten times more often than it can check for the actual tee time. Is there a better way to run my code, so it doesn't get blocked so often?

(At the moment, I'm running it on a headless selenium Chrome browser, but I'm looking to see if I can run the code on a normal browser instead.)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pyautogui as pag

date = "2021-09-19"
st = "08"
et = "09"
golfers = "4"
tabs_opened = 10
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

for _ in range(tabs_opened):
    driver.execute_script(f"window.open('about:blank', 'tab{_+1}');")
    driver.switch_to.window(f"tab{_+1}")
    driver.get(f"https://city-of-burnaby-golf.book.teeitup.com/?course=5fc6afcfd62a025a3123401a&date={date}&end={et}&golfers={golfers}&holes=18&start={st}") #loads the website

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) #assuming new tab is at index 1
driver.close()

tcgbbc = 0 #tracks number of times cloudflare blocks me
wt = 0 #tracks actual times the website has been checked for button
i = 0
_ = 0
starttest = time.perf_counter()
while i < 100: 
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[_%tabs_opened]) #switch to next tab        
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/span/code') #checks if the cloudflare ray id text is there
        print("whoops got blocked by cloudflare")
        tcgbbc+=1
    except:
        print("no cloudflare yay") #it wasn't. yay
        elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-container"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/button') #checks golf burnaby website to see if the button is there
        if len(elem) > 0:
            elem[0].click()
            print("page found")
            break
        else: 
            if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/div/div[1]')) > 0: #if the website's title is there (sometimes it checks and can't find the button, but the page wasn't even loaded)
                print("didn't work") 
                wt+=1
                i+=1   
                driver.refresh() #refreshes the page. seems to be the most time consuming.    
    _+=1  
                         
print(time.perf_counter() - starttest)
time.sleep(1)
driver.close
print(f"Cloudflare blocks: {tcgbbc}, actual checks: {wt}")
```

Comment: have you investigated to see if they have any API for this at all? If you use the proper APIs, the cloud flare problem will be removed, and you wouldn't have to deal with selenium at all.

Comment: variable `_` is often used for value which you don't use - so using `_ = 0` can be missleading and not readable for other. Variables should have names which means something. See more in [PEP 8 --Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: you forgot `()` in last `driver.close()`